# How to format an array of integers in java

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

Currently I have the following method:

```
public static void printDoubleIntArray(int[][] doubleIntArray) {
for (int x = 0; x < doubleIntArray.length; x++) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int y = 0; y < doubleIntArray[x].length; y++) {
    System.out.print(doubleIntArray[x][y]);
    }
}
}
```

It works perfectly when the parameter "doubleIntArray" is only numbers from 0 - 9 like in the following print out:

```
0000000
0000300
0033332
0023323
0022223
0023233
0003332
```

However, if the integers in each element of the array become larger than 9 then I get something like the following:

```
0000000
000121797
001717171716
0101617171617
001616161617
081617161717
001417171716
```

What I would like to know is how do I make the above example print out like so:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0  12  17   9   7
0   0  17  17  17  17  16
0  10  16  17  17  16  17
0   0  16  16  16  16  17
0   8  16  17  16  17  17
0   0  14  17  17  17  16
```

Comment: Try this.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: So do that? Use tab (`\t`) or compute the number of spaces required by checking the length of the double after converting to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("%4d", doubleIntArray[x][y]);
```

4 represents the minimum space that the number will print.

The other options for this method are explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.print(doubleIntArray[x][y] + "\t");
```

\t prints a tab

but in this case it will print something like this: (but i guess thats okay for you)

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   12  17  9   7
0   0   17  17  17  17  16
0   10  16  17  17  16  17
0   0   16  16  16  16  17
0   8   16  17  16  17  17
0   0   14  17  17  17  16
```

Comment: It will heavily depend how OP wants to format the numbers for their consumption. For instance, since it looks for basic display purposes, this is a possible solution. Note that if you want a decent presentation format, it would be better using `String#format` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [`java.text.NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) and a pattern that displays every number with a fixed width.. Then concatenate them all in a single line...

Answer (score 2):

Or use `String.format("%4d", myinteger)` to have each integer occupy 4 chars, and be properly right padded.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options. Firstly, you can use `\t` in the second `for` loop. But I think you could add `\t` and whitespace character to avoid deterioration. Can provide this too, adding `if-else` structure in second for loop. I mean

```
if(doubleIntArray[y].length<10){
    System.out.print(doubleIntArray[x][y] + "\t  ");
    //Tab+two whitespace.
} else {
    if(doubleIntArray[y].length>10) {
        System.out.print(doubleIntArray[x][y] + "\t ");
        //Tab+one whitespace
    } else {
        System.out.print(doubleIntArray[x][y] + "\t");
        //Tab+NO whitespace
    }
}
```

Logic is that I think. Sorry for my answers design. I am on the bus now and I cannot write smoothly. If I had a mistake sorry about that again.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printDoubleIntArray(int[][] doubleIntArray) {
for (int x = 0; x < doubleIntArray.length; x++) {
System.out.println();
 for (int y = 0; y < doubleIntArray[x].length; y++) {
System.out.print(doubleIntArray[x][y],"\t");
    }
 System.out.print("\n");
}
}
```